# On touch listener will not fire up when the user is too fast

Tags: android

I have an `OnTouchListener` and I am waiting for action up and down events.
However when the user touches the surface to quick/short only the down event will fire and not the up event. I fixed it temporarily with a sleep thread but I know for sure this is not the ideal solution. Does anyone have a better idea?

```java
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

 myButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    long timeLastTouch = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        long timeTouchNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        if (timeTouchNow -  timeLastTouch < 400){
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        if ((timeNow - timeLastTouch) < 400) {
                            // do stuff
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tthis is wrong way, do not use `sleep()` method.

Remove this `sleep()` logic, and declare one variable and check last touch time and current touch time difference, if difference is greater the 400 millis then only execute if code.

If any problem you will get then comment, i will solve your issue, Best Luck.

Comment: Okay good idea but where should I check if difference is greater the 400 millis then only execute if code?

Comment: Withing ontouch method

Comment: Can you please take a look at my new code and tell whats wrong with it?

Comment: Is there any problem then i will check

Answer (score 0):

Add touch listener by creating reference on button.

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

 ....

};
```

your are doing `Button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()`

Comment: still have problem

Comment: Yes i have a problem. I want to do it without the sleep thread.

Comment: ok what you really want to do if you get control in on touch section?

Comment: I want to call a function when the user has and pushed the button and left the button

Comment: you want do it on swipe or on simple click listener?